# Array Reduce Polyfill Explanation

Tags: javascript, arrays, polyfills

Apologize in advance for lengthy post. I am trying to understand array reduce polyfill provided by MDN. I could not understand some lines in the polyfill can you explain it please. Below is the code

```
    if (!Array.prototype.reduce) {
      Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'reduce', {
        value: function(callback /*, initialValue*/) {
          if (this === null) {
            throw new TypeError( 'Array.prototype.reduce ' + 
              'called on null or undefined' );
          }
          if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
            throw new TypeError( callback +
              ' is not a function');
          }

          // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
          var o = Object(this);

          // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
          var len = o.length >>> 0; 

          // Steps 3, 4, 5, 6, 7      
          var k = 0; 
          var value;

          if (arguments.length >= 2) {
            value = arguments[1];
          } else {
            while (k < len && !(k in o)) {
              k++; 
            }

            // 3. If len is 0 and initialValue is not present,
            //    throw a TypeError exception.
            if (k >= len) {
              throw new TypeError( 'Reduce of empty array ' +
                'with no initial value' );
            }
            value = o[k++];
          }

          // 8. Repeat, while k < len
          while (k < len) {
            // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
            // b. Let kPresent be ? HasProperty(O, Pk).
            // c. If kPresent is true, then
            //    i.  Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
            //    ii. Let accumulator be ? Call(
            //          callbackfn, undefined,
            //          « accumulator, kValue, k, O »).
            if (k in o) {
              value = callback(value, o[k], k, o);
            }

            // d. Increase k by 1.      
            k++;
          }

          // 9. Return accumulator.
          return value;
        }
      });
    }
```

**Question1:** If you see step 1,

```
var o = Object(this);
```

I have checked both values of o and this, by passing an array to the polyfill method. There is no difference between o and this. They both are arrays(array.isarray returned true on both) with the same array value. Why not use below instead..?

```
var o = this;
```

**Question2:** Step 2

```
var len = o.length >>> 0;
```

Above line seems to right shift the o.length(32 bits). However no.of bits shifted is 0. So what advantage do we get by shifting 0 bits... Why not use below instead...?

```
var len = o.length;
```

**Question 3:** The first while condition inside else as below

```
 while (k < len && !(k in o)) {
    k++;
  }
```

Initially k is set to 0 and it always seems to exist in o. So this while loop condition never gets to be true. So why do we need this while loop, if it never gets inside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Question 1:**

To make sure `reduce` is called on an object as reduce could be called through `Function#call`, `Function#apply` or even bound `Function#bind`:

```js
Array.prototype.reduce.call(undefined, function() {});
```

So when accessing properties such as `length`, an error saying `can't access property **** of undefined` won't be thrown.

NOTE: the example above uses the native `reduce` which actually throws an error if not provided with an object.

**Question 2:**

To always have a valid integer value as `length` (even if it doesn't exist):

```js
console.log(5 >>> 0);         // 5
console.log(5.5 >>> 0);       // 5
console.log("5" >>> 0);       // 5
console.log("hello" >>> 0);   // 0
console.log(undefined >>> 0); // 0
```

**Question 3:**

To deal with sparse arrays:

```js
var arr = [5, 6];
arr[7000000] = 7;

arr.reduce(function(acc, v, i) {
  console.log("index:", i);
}, 0);
```

It won't go through all the indices from `0` to `7000000`, only those that really exist.

Comment: Re: Question 3, you could also have `arr = new Array(700000)` and then `arr[1] = someValue`. Then, `0 in arr` would be `false` but `1 in arr` would be `true`, so in this case you would still get `k > 0`

Comment: Also re: Question 1 you can call `(5).length`, but you can't call `(undefined).length`. I think this is done for safety reasons, although they also have the `=== null` check.

Comment: @ExplosionPills That was actually my example at first. I rolled back to it. BTW the pollyfill does have the `=== null` check. They should use `==` instead of `===` to include `undefined` too.

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir, step 1 converts 'this' into Object or an array(I understand array is some kind of object in js)? Sorry if it was a dumb question

Comment: @gregchap Into an object. Actually if it's already an object (real object, array, ...) it won't do anything, it will just return it (try in the console: `var arr = []; Object(arr) === arr;`). If it's a native value such as a string, a number, ... then it will convert it into `String`, `Number`, ... instance. If it's `undefined` then into an empty object.

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir Please explain the statement more. I suppose it converts something into object. Some reason if an array is correctly passed, this and Object(this) wont make any difference. But to be safe, they included it to make sure undefined or other types are passed to the polyfill. Am I correct?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I actually did that.. when I did Object(5) is created a native number object. But on array it seems to be not much different. I understand now

Comment: @gregchap Yes. Specially `undefined`. I've edited the answer to mention why. Because of the **`can't access property **** of undefined`**.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir just saying... your Question3 example might not be correct. The first while loop in the else condition gets inside the loop when we have something like this: var arr=[]; arr[3] =4; In this case the while loop condition becomes true and k gets incremented and k becomes 3. However your example might suit well for the second while condition outside else {}

Comment: @gregchap Ah! Yeah! The first `while` loop is only used if we called `reduce` with no **initial value**. That loop then fetches the first value from the array and use it as the initial value. It uses the same concept as the second `while` loop which is (the concept I mean) explained in the **Question 3** section above. It just ignores indexes that do not exist.

Answer (score -1):

The following approach works :

```
var Arr = [1,2,3,4]

 Array.prototype.myreduce = function(callback,initialvale){

    var result ;
    var resultvalue = initialvale
    
    for(var key =0;key<this.length;key++){
     
        var resultvalue =callback(resultvalue,this[key])
        
        }
    
    return resultvalue;
  
  
} 


var customvalued = Arr.myreduce(function(total,value){

    //console.log(total,value)

     if(value%2==0){
        total.push(value)
    } 
    
    return total 
    
},[])

console.log(customvalued)
```